# Can we find $n$ such that $3061\cdot2^n +1$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p=3061$. Can we find an integer $n$ such that $2^n p+1$ is prime? If there is no such $n$, how can we prove it? Or does such $n$ always exist for prime $p$?

(More generally, instead of $p=3061$, you can try e.g. $p=5297,5897,7013,8423,\ldots$ -- there are quite a few primes $p$ for which brute force does not seem to work.)

*Motivation:* questions like these arise naturally while reading the paper 
 [On the density of odd integers of the form $(p − 1)2^{-n}$ and related questions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X7990043X)
by Paul Erdös and Andrew Odlyzko.

Comment: `n=33288;p=3061*2^n+1;ispseudoprime(p)`=`1`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers and comments! Regarding the part "if there is no such $n$, how to prove it?" - the answer is two-fold: (1) [covering sets](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=SierpinskiNumber) and (2) [algebraic factorizations](https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/FQ/Scanned/33-3/izotov.pdf); e.g. [question 2043169](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043169/) has further relevant info.

Comment: See also: [Does every Sierpinski number have a finite congruence covering?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683082/)

Comment: There are *infinitely many primes* $p$ for which $2^np+1$ is always composite (for all $n\in{\mathbb N}$). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688599/can-we-find-n-such-that-3061-cdot2n-1-is-prime/3697612#3697612) for details.

Comment: The prime $3061\cdot 2^{33288}+1$ seems to have been first found by Buell and Young circa 1988. Source: [T5k: `3061*2^33288 + 1`](https://t5k.org/primes/page.php?id=17633)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are Proth numbers so you can apply [Proth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth_prime#Primality_testing) for efficient primality testing (see also [Are there primes $p=47\cdot 2^n+1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847277).). This way, we can verify that the pseudoprime posted by @DmitryEzhov in comments is indeed a prime by choosing $a=3$, $N=3061\cdot 2^{33288}+1$, because
$$
a^{\frac{N-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod{N}.
$$
(e.g. `a := 3: p := 3061*2^33288+1: is((Power(a, (p-1)/2) mod p) = p-1)` in Maple).

Also [Effective Primality Test for $p2^n+1$, $p$ prime, $n>1$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.06070.pdf) could be of interest. It especially mentions:

> Sierpinski numbers of the second kind are integers $k$ such that $k2^n + 1$ is not prime for all positive integers $n$.

So in your case, if the Sierpinski number $k=p$ happens to be a prime, you will not find $n$ such that $p2^n+1$ is a prime. There are infinitely many such numbers, the  $k=271129$ is conjectured to be the smallest (see Prime Sierpinski problem). See Alex's answer for more examples.

Even more reading [The Sierpiński Problem: Definition and Status](http://www.prothsearch.com/sierp.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @Sil - now I also see some interesting links at OEIS A040076.

Comment: @Alex Right, and especially A057192 for prime $k$. There is a big list https://oeis.org/A057192/b057192.txt, since $3061$ is $438$-th prime, in the list there is 438 33288, which means $n=33288$ is indeed smallest one giving prime. You can check other primes in your list.

Comment: This is the "Seventeen of Bust" problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeen_or_Bust), see also https://www.primegrid.com/forum_thread.php?id=1647

Comment: @GerryMyerson I found this reference to be a little more organized, making it easy to identify the prime for $3061$: http://www.prothsearch.com/sierp.html.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete solution but some observations. Let $a_n=2^np+1$.

I.  If $n$ is odd then $3\,|\,a_n$.

Pf:  Indeed  $3061\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so $a_n\equiv 2^n+1\pmod 3$ and the claim follows.

II.  If $n\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ then $5\,|\,a_n$

Pf:  Indeed, $3061\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ so $a_n\equiv 2^n+1\pmod 5$ and the claim follows.

So you only need to worry about $n\equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  For those there does not appear to be a simple congruence.  Indeed, for $n\in \{1,\cdots 10\}$ the least prime which divides $a_{4n}$ is, respectively, $$\{17,19,17,797, 17,821,17,31,17,59\cdots\}$$

From which we are led to conjecture that $n\equiv 4 \mod 8\implies 17\,|\,a_n$, which is easily proven (since $3061\equiv 1\pmod {17}$ and $2^4\equiv -1 \pmod {17}$).

That just leaves $n\equiv 0\pmod 8$ to study.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Do you think it would be hopeless to try proving that for *every prime* $p$ there exists $n$ for which $2^np+1$ is prime?

Comment: Hopeless is a strong word.  But I think it would be a very impressive result.

Comment: It turns out that *infinitely many primes* $p$ are such that $2^np+1$ is composite for all natural $n$ -- i.e. inifinitely many primes are [Sierpinski numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number). I added another answer showing this,

Answer (score 1):

Carrying forward the observations of @lulu:

If $n = 0$ (mod 8), then $19| a_n$ for $n=8, 80, 152, 224,...$ i.e. for $8$ and every ninth multiple of $8$.

For since $2^8=9$ (mod $19$), and $3061=2$ (mod $19$), then $2^8\cdot3061+1=9\cdot2+1=0$ (mod 19). Further, since $2^{72}=1$ (mod $19$), then $19|a_n$ for $n=8, 80, 152, 224,...$.

In the same way we find that $31|a_n$ for $n=32, 72, 112, 152,...$, i.e. for every fifth multiple of $8$ beginning with $32$.

$37|a_n$ for $n=48, 120, 192, 264,...$, or every ninth multiple of $8$ from $48$.

$43|a_n$ for $n=32, 88, 144, 200,...$,i.e. for every seventh multiple of $8$ beginning with $32$.

Once more, $53|a_n$ for $n=80, 184, 288, 392...$, or every thirteenth multiple of $8$ from $80$.

Thus, even allowing for some overlap, it seems that with just these five primes we sieve out$$\frac19+\frac15+\frac19+\frac17+\frac{1}{13}>\frac12$$of $a_n$ as necessarily composite.

If we did not have an accepted answer to the question, this could have at least further narrowed the search.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elaborate answer to the question: *does such $n$ always exist for prime* $k=p$?
(This complements the answers given earlier.)

[Sierpinski number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number) is an odd integer $k$ such that $k\cdot2^n+1$ is composite for all $n\in{\mathbb N}$.
Sierpinski's paper [Sur un probleme concernant les nombres $k\cdot2^n+1$](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=edm-001:1960:15#133) (1960) proved that there are infinitely many $k$ with this property.
Namely, he proved that *if $k$ satisfies two congruences*:
$$
k \equiv 1 \ ({\rm mod}\ q_1), \ \quad  q_1=(2^{32}-1)\cdot641=2753074036095, \tag{1}
$$
$$
k \equiv -1 \ ({\rm mod}\ q_2) \quad  q_2=(2^{32}+1)/641\,=\,6700417, \qquad\quad  \tag{2}
$$
then $k$ is a Sierpinski number. We will now prove the following simple corollary of Sierpinski's result.

**Corollary:** *Infinitely many primes are Sierpinski numbers.*

*Proof.* We will show that infinitely many primes satisfy Sierpinski's congruences $(1)$, $(2)$.
Indeed, choose
$$
a=15511380746462593381, \qquad q=q_1 q_2=18446744073709551615.
$$
Then all terms $k_m$ of the arithmetic progression
$$
k_m=a+mq,\quad m\in{\mathbb N}, \tag{3}
$$
satisfy both congruences $(1)$ and $(2)$. So all $k_m$ are Sierpinski numbers.

But note that $\gcd(a,q)=1$. Therefore, by [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions),
there are infinitely many primes in the progression $a+mq \ \ (3). \ \ $ Q.E.D.

Here are the first five primes in progression $(3)$:
$$52404868893881696611$$
$$273765797778396315991$$
$$347552774073234522451$$
$$827168119989682864441$$
$$1306783465906131206431$$